# Using a different color for a section of a line in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting a variety of lines for my plot, using ggplot, each with a specified color. I am plotting estimates as a function of Year (so, these are time series data).
However, two of the lines that I plotted have overlap for the first 138 years. What I would like to do is shade those first 138 years (corresponding to the first 22 values) as black for those two curves, but I haven't come across anything useful that shows how to isolate a section of curves like that. Would that be possible?

This is what I have done, so far (which works just fine):

```
library(ggplot2)

gg5 <- ggplot(data = xcel, aes(x = Year)) + 
          geom_line(aes(y = GLocation45), color = "blue", linetype = "twodash") + 
          geom_line(aes(y = GLocation85), color = "red", linetype = "twodash") + 
          geom_line(aes(y = Glocationco), color = "green", linetype = "twodash")

> dput(xcel[1:10,])

structure(list(Year = c(7L, 14L, 21L, 28L, 35L, 42L, 49L, 56L, 
63L, 70L), GLocation45 = c(180.06, 187.96, 181.03, 173.14, 184.26, 
183.7, 188.59, 178.21, 189.23, 184.63), GScale45 = c(56.83, 63.86, 
62.21, 51.87, 60.28, 60.74, 62.11, 58.22, 60.94, 60.73), GShape45 = c(0.004, 
-0.17, -0.16, -0.03, -0.1, -0.19, -0.17, 0.07, -0.15, -0.05), 
GLocation85 = c(180.06, 187.96, 181.03, 173.14, 184.26, 183.7, 
188.59, 178.21, 189.23, 184.63), GScale85 = c(5.68, 63.86, 
62.21, 51.87, 60.28, 60.74, 62.11, 58.22, 60.94, 60.73), 
GShape85 = c(0.004, -0.16, -0.16, -0.03, -0.1, -0.19, -0.17, 
0.07, -0.15, -0.05), Glocationco = c(174.58, 167.46, 178.54, 
183.37, 181.54, 187.89, 197.58, 194.36, 212.71, 198.84), 
GScaleco = c(59.2, 51.42, 57.82, 62.86, 61.84, 65.84, 72.01, 
64.4, 75.7, 62.69), GShapeco = c(-0.06, 0.27, 0.002, -0.02, 
-0.005, -0.11, -0.26, 3e-04, -0.29, 0.05)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The objects "GLocation45" and "GLocation85" are the ones overlapping with the same values for the first 138 years (essentially, the first 22 values correspond to the first 138 years, so the first 22 values of each these objects are identical), so I would like those sections of the curves to be in black, and then let them continue as blue and red, respectively, after those 138 years.

Would that be possible?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of `xcel` with `dput()`?

Comment: Ian Campbell Thanks for your response. Okay - I just added a sample in my post above from dput (it shows objects "Year" and "GLocation45")

Comment: Unfortunately, the output of `dput` is not formed correctly. Can you output something that will make your code run? Maybe `dput(xcel[1:10,])`?

Comment: @IanCampbell Okay - I added the output from what I received from "dput(xcel[1:10,])" in my post above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution where you just need to subset your data to draw each line.

```
library(ggplot2)

#Number of rows, from 1 to n, where the lines overlap.
#According to your question this should be 138 using the complete dataset
n<-5

ggplot(data = xcel, aes(x = Year)) + 
  #Subset data for black line, i.e., shared line
  geom_line(aes(y = GLocation45), data = xcel[1:n,],
            color = "black", linetype = "twodash") + 
  #Subset for the red line. i.e., rest of the data 
  geom_line(aes(y = GLocation85), data = xcel[n:nrow(xcel),],
            color = "red", linetype = "twodash") + 
  #Draw green line normally, without subsets
  geom_line(aes(y = Glocationco),
            color = "green", linetype = "twodash")
```

[image: plot shared line]

Comment: Ah, yes, this is what I was looking for! Thank you so much! I noticed in your plot that the blue curve is missing, though? GLocation45 would be in a blue color, but following the black section (like you did with the red curve following the black part - both would have the same black part). Also, just to correct a detail, the first 22 values for objects "GLocation45" and "GLocation85" would be the equivalent of 138 years, so really it is the first 22 values that should in black. In that case, when subsetting, should it be "xcel[1:22,]" for GLocation45 and GLocation85? Thanks,

Comment: I figured it out - I just added a new geom_line() after subsetting 1:22 in the first geom_line containing either "GLocation45" or "GLocation85". So, that way, values 1 to 22 would be under the color black for both of these objects (both in a separate geom_line), and then create two new separate geom_line() to do 22:34 as either blue or red, effectively connecting to the black piece. :) Thanks again!